# Production Build getting failed with FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: angular, webpack, tsconfig

while running running production build its getting failed and showing Fatal Error: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory and while running development build its getting passed

I tried to run using set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8172 && npm run build:production , in this case build is getting passed in local but same command is not working in server and getting failed

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin = require('html-webpack-harddisk-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

const devServerHost = 'localhost';
const devServerPort = 8080;
const isProd = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');
const isDevServer = !isProd && path.basename(require.main.filename) === 'webpack-dev-server.js';

function getPlugins() {


    let htmlWebpackOptions = {
        inject: false,
        filename: "../Index.cshtml",
        template: "./Index_Template.cshtml",
        isDevServer: false
    };

    if (!isProd && isDevServer) {
        htmlWebpackOptions.alwaysWriteToDisk = true;
        htmlWebpackOptions.isDevServer = true;
        htmlWebpackOptions.devServerUrlRoot = `http://${devServerHost}:${devServerPort}`;
    };

    let plugins = [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery',
            moment: 'moment'
        }),

        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: isDevServer ? '[name].bundle.css' : '[name].bundle.[contenthash].cs',
            chunkFilename: isDevServer ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css'
        }),
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/cptable/),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(htmlWebpackOptions),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)fesm5/,
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'), {}
        )

    ];

    if (!isProd) {
        if (isDevServer) {
            plugins.push(new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin());
        }
        plugins.push(new WebpackNotifierPlugin({ title: 'ICC Build' }));
    }

    return plugins;
}

module.exports = {
    mode: isProd ? 'production' : 'development',
    entry: {
        //Order is important to have vendor before app
        vendor: ['./Scripts/vendor-bundleconfig.ts'],
        app: ['./app/main']
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.[chunkhash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        library: 'XLSX'
    },
    plugins: getPlugins(),
    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './should_be_empty',
        host: devServerHost,
        port: devServerPort,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // tslint
            { test: /\.ts$/, enforce: "pre", loader: "tslint-loader", exclude: '/node_modules', options: { emitErrors: true, failOnHint: true } },

            // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
            { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "awesome-typescript-loader", exclude: '/node_modules', },

            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            {
                enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader", "exclude": [
                    // instead of /\/node_modules\//
                    path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules')
                ]
            },
            // CSS
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            // CSS

            //{ test: /\.css$/, use: MiniCssExtractPlugin.extract({ use: [{ loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, url: true } }] }) },

            // Images
            { test: /\.woff2?$|\.ttf$|\.eot$|\.svg$|\.png$|\.gif$/, use: [{ loader: "file-loader", query: { name: "[path][name].[ext]" } }] },
            {
                // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
                // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
                test: /[\\]@angular[\\]core[\\].+\.js$/,
                parser: { system: true },  // enable SystemJS
            }

        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
            }),
        ]
    },

    node: { fs: "empty" },
    externals: [
        { './jszip': 'jszip' },
        { './cptable': 'var cptable' },
        { jquery: 'jQuery' }
    ]

};
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Test.online",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --colors --port 8080 --content-base ./should_be_empty",
    "build": "rimraf dist && rimraf Index.cshtml && webpack --color",
    "build:production": "set NODE_ENV=production&&webpack -p && set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8172",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --color",
    "test": "karma start --single-run --browsers ChromeHeadless --reporters=progress karma.conf.js",
    "test:watch": "karma start --auto-watch --browsers ChromeHeadless --reporters=progress karma.conf.js",
    "test:build": "karma start --single-run --browsers ChromeHeadless --reporters=junit,progress karma.conf.js",
    "test:debug": "karma start --auto-watch --browsers ChromeDebugging --reporters=progress karma.conf.js"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "^0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
    "@types/node": "^12.6.4",
    "angular-ui-tree": "^2.22.6",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.1.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-replace-webpack-plugin": "^2.5.5",
    "html-webpack-harddisk-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.99.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "jasmine-enzyme": "^3.8.3",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.13",
    "ng-text-truncate-2": "^1.0.1",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "react": "^15.6.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.7",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.18.0",
    "tslint-loader": "3.6.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5",
    "webpack": "^4.35.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/angular": "1.5.12",
    "@types/angular-mocks": "1.5.10",
    "@types/chroma-js": "^1.4.1",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.53",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.7.1",
    "@types/react": "^15.0.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.0",
    "@types/ui-grid": "0.0.38",
    "@uirouter/angular-hybrid": "~8.0.0",
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.20",
    "@uirouter/visualizer": "^7.0.0",
    "angular": "1.6.10",
    "angular-animate": "1.6.10",
    "angular-file-saver": "1.1.3",
    "angular-local-storage": "^0.7.1",
    "angular-mocks": "1.5.7",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^0.4.8",
    "angular-ui-tree": "2.22.6",
    "canvg-browser": "^1.0.0",
    "chroma-js": "^1.4.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.1.3",
    "fileapi": "^2.1.1",
    "humanize-duration": "^3.18.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.7.0",
    "moment": "2.10.6",
    "ng-text-truncate-2": "^1.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.0.4",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "ui-router-visualizer": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-filter-warnings-plugin": "^1.2.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.11.19",
    "xlsx-style": "https://registry.npmjs.org/xlsx-style/-/xlsx-style-0.8.13.tgz",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "-vs-binding": {
    "AfterBuild": [
      "build"
    ],
    "ProjectOpened": [
      "watch"
    ]
  }
}
```

below error in console i am getting both in local and server

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[237840:0000029FB4CC4C40]   281470 ms: Mark-sweep 1331.3 (1453.8) -> 1321.9 (1457.3) MB, 3742.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.097, current mu = 0.048) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[237840:0000029FB4CC4C40]   284506 ms: Mark-sweep 1335.2 (1457.3) -> 1326.1 (1457.3) MB, 2885.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.074, current mu = 0.049) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 000000D5138DC5C1]
Security context: 0x01af6e61e6e9 <JSObject>
    1: _(aka _) [0000033529102201] [C:\git-angular\ICC\Server\AuraLiteOnline\PwC.Aura.Online\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\node_modules\terser\dist\bundle.min.js:~1] [pc=000000D515B25DD6](this=0x02b3515826f1 <undefined>,n=0x013bb58a2bb9 <String[4]: punc>,i=0x02b351586629 <String[1]: .>,o=0x02b3515826f1 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 2->3...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF7E490C6AA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506
 2: 00007FF7E48E7416 node::MakeCallback+4534
 3: 00007FF7E48E7D90 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF7E4C0189E v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF7E4C017CF v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF7E4DE7F94 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620
 7: 00007FF7E4DDEF76 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24550
 8: 00007FF7E4DDD5CC v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17980
 9: 00007FF7E4DE6317 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2327
10: 00007FF7E4DE6396 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2454
11: 00007FF7E4F10637 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+55
12: 00007FF7E4F8DCD9 v8::internal::operator<<+74697
13: 000000D5138DC5C`enter code here`1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
```

someone please suggest any solution to fix this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found the fix for above issue in server , memory issue was there so its causing above error, to make it work i added below task just after "npm install"
 next step -> "npm install increase memory limit" and after that -> have to run this task "increase-memory-limit".

production build getting successful after this changes.

Comment: Can you please provide me with these steps in detail? I am facing same issue with my vue project